# Как удалять запись в БД динамически?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Всем привет. Есть такая ситуация. Списком вываливается все записи, напротив каждой записи есть иконка "удалить". Уже сделал так, что при нажатии на иконку запись удаляется из БД. Но хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы выпадало окно с подтверждением "удалить запись?", с кнопками "да" и "нет". Так вот, как это реализовать?

Точнее, как динамически передать в форму id записи?

Comment: @duddeniska, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с правками вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать стандартный диалог JavaScript - это `confirm();`. На практике будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var itemBox = '.my-item';       // контейнер записи, id записи храним в data-id
var $itemDel = $('.btn-del');   // ссылка удалить

$itemDel.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = confirm('Действительно удалить из базы?');
    if (result) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $thisItem = $this.closest(itemBox);
        var thisIndex = $thisItem.attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
              url:'тут путь до скрипта который удаляет',
              data:{'itemid':thisIndex },
              success:function(r){
                  $thisItem.slideUp(300,function(){
                      $thisItem.remove();
                  });
              }
        });
    }
});
```

Ну и "живой пример" как это работает: http://jsfiddle.net/edv5exqz/2/

Удачи Вам!